# Validate presence of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I don't get it I have the following models:

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller
  # I have tried both with the validates existence gem:
  validates :existence => {:allow_nil => false}
  # And normally...
  validates_presence_of :seller
end
```

But nothing works if I do the following:

```
seller = Seller.new()
seller.cars.build()
seller.save # I get => false @messages={:seller=>["does not exist"], :seller_id=>["does not exist"]}
```

I should be able to do this right?

It's like - it's validating the associated model before the mother-object has been saved - and i have NOT defined a validates_associated or something like that.

Any clue? Or am I getting the order of saving and validating all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this in the past, and have used "inverse_of" to solve it. You also need "accepts_nested_attributes_for". So in the seller, you would want to change your code to the following:

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :seller
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
end
```

Comment: Actually, you might not need accepts_nested_attributes_for in this case. Check it out both ways and see which one works :)

Comment: Hmm I don't really get your solution. I don't want to turn the validation of the associated model off - I just wanted it to pass. In my world, it should start by validating and saving the mother-object and then validate and save the associated models. But maybe I'm just all wrong about that?

Comment: You aren't going to turn the validation off. You leave it on. The problem is that the car is not aware of who it belongs to before you save. Adding :inverse_of tells the Car to look back to the Seller to associate itself.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to add :inverse_of :seller - not :series!

Comment: Sorry - I ran into some other issue that really needed my attention - as soon as I have tried this out, I'll get back (accept the answer if it works)

Answer (score 1):

`Seller` does not exist because it has not been saved in the database, it's just in the memory, and so `Car` does not know `Seller's` id which it needs to know - it has to add it to the seller_id column. So you first have to save `Seller` and you don't need the validates_presence_of :seller call in `Car`.

Comment: This is not correct. The association is able to be made before saving the Seller if you follow the pattern of my answer.

Comment: @andrewpthorp Can you please specify exactly what is not correct?

Comment: The Seller does not need to be saved first. If you add :inverse_of => :series to the has_many relationship on the Seller, the car will make the association before the save, and update the seller_id correctly during the save.

Comment: @andrewpthorp And if I don't add :inverse_of would then Seller need to be saved first? And, second, how does Car know Seller's id when Seller has not yet been saved? And, third, what is :series?

Comment: sorry, I meant :seller, not :series. Also, if you weren't going to do something like this, you would need to save it first or manually set up the  inverse, by changing line 2 to: c = seller.cars.build(), c.seller = seller.

Comment: @andrewpthorp How would `Car` know `Seller's` id if you did not save Seller first?